# How to limit defined complexType in XSD Schema file

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have defined a **object** sub-type in an XSD file as such:

```
  <xs:complexType  name="object">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="state"  maxOccurs="unbounded"  type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

As you can see, the `<state>` tag is configured so that it can appear any number of times (from 1). So this would be an example, where I use the defined `<object>`:

```
  <System>
    <object_1>
      <state>string_1</state>
      <state>string_2</state>
      <state>string_3</state>
    <object_1>
    <object_2>
      <state>string_4</state>
    <object_2>
    ...
  </System>
```

However, there is a special situation where I need to define an **object** sub-type (`<object_n>`) with **exactly** 2 `<state>` elements/tags (no more and no less):

```
<object_n>
  <state>string_n1</state>
  <state>string_n2</state>
</object_n>
```

Is there a way to extend/modify/limit this type when I declare it in a Schema file so that it is clear that it must contain only two sub-elements?

```
<xs:element  type="object">
  <xs:somewayToLimitChildren/>
```

Actually, the object sub-type is more comlpex, hence the need to make it a sub-type.

Comment: `maxOccurs="undefined"` should be  `maxOccurs="unbounded"`

Comment: You are right, Thanks! Edited according to Kachna comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new type using `xs:restriction` :

```
<xs:complexType name="newObject">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="object">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="state"  minOccurs="2"  maxOccurs="2" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>    
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```